# pkg install -forge general bash: pkg: command not found

Tags: debian, command-not-found, octave

I'm running Debian stretch and want to be able to run my MATLAB code, using the GNU Octave packages.

I type this into terminal

```
pkg install -forge general
```

and it gives me this error

```
bash: pkg: command not found
```

Any ideas? I've attempted to install this before, so maybe I did something weird last time, but as far as I can remember, I had the same problem the first time. I've had a look around the forums, but I didn't find anything that I understood enough to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s an Octave command, not a shell command, so you need to run it from an Octave prompt. Starting from a shell prompt, start Octave:

```
octave
```

Then run you `pkg install` command.

*However*, the `general` Octave package is included in the Debian Octave packages so you shouldn’t need to install it like that.

If you’re actually trying to install Octave, run

```
sudo apt install octave
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you! The Octave site did not make that clear at all